# Programatically registered spring bean misses a dependency

Tags: java, spring

I would like to register a spring bean programatically (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer) with

```
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
container.setQueueNames(queueName);
container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
beanFactory.registerSingleton(name, container);
```

the containing class implements InitializingBean where beanFactory gets injected via

```
@Autowired
private void setBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
}
```

The problem is, that the resulting bean does not work properly. Debugging showed that for example the ApplicationEventPublisher was not set on [SimpleMessageListenerContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html) which implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware.

In turn, when I register the bean via @Bean annotation it works properly:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer zuteilungsProviderContainer(
        @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        MessageListenerAdapter tourZuteilungenListenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(Q_BRIEFING_WINDOW);
    container.setMessageListener(tourZuteilungenListenerAdapter);
    return container;
}
```

When creating the bean programatically, for some reason the wiring or post processing does not work properly. I debugged a lot but I got lost in spring details.

What do I miss? I would be very grateful for any hint.

Comment: Did you "refresh" the application context after registering your bean?

Comment: Can you show SimpleMessageListenerContainer class

Comment: @pvpkiran: Here is the class http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html

Comment: @AndrewWhite, I tried but got an exception `GenericApplicationContext does not support multiple refresh attempts: just call 'refresh' once`. Apparently, the context had already refreshed (not by my though). Do I maybe have a problem with order of registering the beans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
beanFactory.autowireBean(container);
beanFactory.initializeBean(container, name);
```

Add this before the line

```
beanFactory.registerSingleton(name, container);
```